# Getting managers from an oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got a table (`TB_EMP`) that has all the employees of the company, among others, it has the following fields:

```
mm_user_name
mm_manager_id
mm_emp_id
mm_name
```

What I need to do, is get all the employees that have subordinates, in other words, every one, who's `mm_emp_id` is also someone else's `mm_manager_id`. I was thinking of doing a join on self, then counting the times the the employees id has come up in the table, in the field `mm_manager_id` and in the end getting the ones where this count is larger than 0. What would be the query to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.mm_user_name
FROM TB_EMP AS t1
INNER JOIN TB_EMP AS t2 
        ON t1.mm_emp_id = t2.mm_manager_id
```

Just a simple inner self-join. I didn't get why you want to count the occurences of `mm_manager_id`?

Comment: Yes, now I get it. I wanted to count and get where there is a match, but an inner join does make more sense

Answer (score 1):

you need to put join only .. no need to count on join